# How to add a new column to a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Currently I have a dataframe like below

```
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
+---+
```

and I want to add a new column called `product_id`.

```
+-----------+
| product_id|
+-----------+
|          A|
|          B|
|          C|
+-----------+
```

For each `id` in the dataframe, I want to add all `product_id`:

```
+---+----------+
| id|product_id|
+---+----------+
|  0|         A|
|  0|         B|
|  0|         C|
|  1|         A|
|  1|         B|
|  1|         C|
+---+----------+
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please share the code instead of the image. Check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and If needed we will assist you

Answer (score 0):

This is generation of a sample dataframe

```
df = spark.range(2)
df.show()

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
+---+
```

---

Option 1: [stack](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#stack)

```
stack_df = df.selectExpr("*","stack(3,'A','B','C') as product_id")
stack_df.show()

+---+----------+
| id|product_id|
+---+----------+
|  0|         A|
|  0|         B|
|  0|         C|
|  1|         A|
|  1|         B|
|  1|         C|
+---+----------+
```

Option 2: [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#explode)

```
explode_df = df.selectExpr("*","explode(array('A','B','C')) as product_id")
explode_df.show()

+---+----------+
| id|product_id|
+---+----------+
|  0|         A|
|  0|         B|
|  0|         C|
|  1|         A|
|  1|         B|
|  1|         C|
+---+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer David. If the array is a variable (not known before hand), can I still use stack or explode?

Comment: This answers the original question. Please revert back your edit and open a new post for the altered question

Comment: Reverted and posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/71507765