# How to add (explode) a new column from a list to a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Currently I have a dataframe like below, and I want to add a new column called `product_id`.

```
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
+---+
```

The values for `product_id` is derived from a `List[String]()`, an example of this List can be:
`sampleList = List(A, B, C)`

For each `id` in the dataframe, I want to add all `product_id`:

```
+---+----------+
| id|product_id|
+---+----------+
|  0|         A|
|  0|         B|
|  0|         C|
|  1|         A|
|  1|         B|
|  1|         C|
+---+----------+
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `crossJoin` method.

```
val ls1 = List(0,1)
val df1 = ls1.toDF("id")
val sampleList = List("A", "B", "C")
val df2 = sampleList.toDF("product_id")
val df = df1.crossJoin(df2)
df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Generation of a sample dataframe & list**

```
val sampleList = List("A", "B", "C")

val df = spark.range(2)
```

---

```
df.show()

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
+---+
```

**Solution**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode,array,lit}

val explode_df = df.withColumn("product_id",explode(array(sampleList map lit: _*)))
```

---

```
explode_df.show()

+---+----------+
| id|product_id|
+---+----------+
|  0|         A|
|  0|         B|
|  0|         C|
|  1|         A|
|  1|         B|
|  1|         C|
+---+----------+
```